# How to close Performance Explorer in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have one pecuiliar bug in VS 2012 and 2013. Once you open Perfromance Explorer (for example by going to Analyze -> Profiler -> New performance session).. there is no way you can rid off of it.

I open studio afresh, close the Perf Explorer window, press Ctrl-Shift-S or Save All (just in case), exit.. Once I start the studio again the window is on the same place as it was..

**Anyone knows how to close it for good?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way that I have found to keep the window closed is to delete or move the performance files that are saved by VS.  By default they are stored in the root of the solution directory alongside the solution file.

Comment: yeah.. I found that too.. but I am convinced this is a bug.. hoped someone knew a way around. what if I need these files.. right?